# Best way store an index of an index using Redis?

Tags: node.js, database, indexing, redis

Yes, the question is confusing. If you know a better way to ask what I'm asking, please do share!

I'm designing an agnostic REST API using NodeJS and Redis. The server is set up to index any fields that are set to do so in a model specification.

Ex:

```
// user object
{ 
  firstName: 'Peter',
  lastName: 'Boyd',
  role: 'worker'
}
```

Right now, when a user is added, the field that gets indexed is the "role" field. The database will look like this:

```
// user objects stored as regular key
key: "users:<ID1>" | value: "{ ...userData }"

// "role" indexes stored as hash key
hash key: "users:role" | field: "worker" | value: "users:<ID1>"
```

When a second user is added that also has the value "worker" for the "role" field, this is what the database looks like:

```
// user objects stored as regular key
key: "users:<ID1>" | value: "{ ...userData1 }"
key: "users:<ID2>" | value: "{ ...userData2 }"

// "role" indexes stored as hash key (previous value gets replaced)
hash key: "users:role" | field: "worker" | value: "users:role:worker"

// "worker" value for "role" gets created as list
key: "users:role:worker" | value: [ "users:<ID1>", "users:<ID2>" ]
```

This way, the secondary index doesn't get created unless it's required in order to save space. The secondary index is a list that holds the keys of the user objects. The initial index value holds the key of this list as it's value which is "users:role:worker" in this case.

This works well except when multiple users get created at the same time with an empty database. This indexing design is not state-less, and therefor it causes weird things to happen.

My question is, how can I improve on this design? I've thought of a couple solutions, but they each have a few drawbacks.

#### **Possible Solution #1**

Create the secondary index (the list with the key "users:role:worker") from the beginning. However this seems like it would be a waste of space considering it would create two entries for every field that has an index, which is often unnecessary.

#### **Possible Solution #2**

Instead of storing the ID as the value for every index, store a string array of IDs. This would prevent that secondary list from being created. New user IDs would just be added to the string array. However, this method means that the string array would be overwritten whenever a new user is added. This leads me to believe simultaneous requests would just overwrite each other, leading to unwanted outcomes.

---

What do you think? Is there a better design to handle this?

Help and feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you consider using RediSearch? http://redisearch.io
It has this exact "Tags" behavior see: https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Tags.html

Comment: Redisearch would be great, but I'm using Redis Enterprise Cloud to easily manage the cluster or nodes, and it doesn't integrate with Redisearch (as of Spring 2019).

Comment: If you're Redis Cloud Pro user you should have it built in https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rv/

Comment: Good call, but I'm only using the essentials version at the moment. Pro is a bit pricier. I might upgrade once the product is launched and profitable. RediSearch is a beast that offers a lot of other awesome functionality as well.

Comment: essentials  now supports all of Redis Labs modules including RediSearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing solution #1 with a twist, and it works well. Instead of setting the schema specification to `index: true` for this particular field, I set up a `deepIndex: true` which automatically creates the secondary index from the beginning.

This means any field that will likely have shared values between several instances will be "deeply indexed" in this way.